# По RDP успешно залогинился несуществующий пользователь, как так?

Tags: windows, администрирование, rdp

В RDP ломится непонятно кто с успешной проверкой подлинности несуществующего пользователя.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, это вообще как, если пользователя блин не существует в системе вообще?

Comment: Неужто рдп у тебя в интернет выставлен?

Comment: @donRumata Ну адрес, на скрине, уж явно не из приватной сети. ;-)

Comment: А, тупанул, да. Тогда у меня ещё больше вопросов: кто в здравом уме выставляет решето в интернет? Где sstp/openvpn?

Comment: @donRumata мопед тьфу IP не мой, я просто [разместил](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/53427945#53427945)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как выясняется, слова "успешная проверка подлинности пользователя" в описании события вопреки всем ожиданиям вовсе не означают, что кто-то смог залогиниться в систему. Данное событие говорит лишь о том, что кто-то пытался подключиться через RDP, и смог дойти до окна ввода логина/пароля. Подробнее - [тут](https://ponderthebits.com/2018/02/windows-rdp-related-event-logs-identification-tracking-and-investigation/).

> **TL;DR:** NOT AN AUTHENTICATION. Someone launched an RDP client,
>   specified the target machine (possibly with a username and domain),
>   and hit enter to make a successful network connection to the target.
>   Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: Нормально так можно обделаться, если толпа ботов пройдет такую проверку подлинности, а админ не в курсе что это :)